# Task properties "Form_URN", "Outcome", "%Complete" suddenly gone from SPD Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks, reusable-workflow

**Scenario:**

1. We have created one reusable workflow
2. In this workflow "**Start Custom Task Process**" action is used for assigning the task.
3. In the workflow, We were accessing two task properties **Form_URN** & **Outcome**.
4. Everything was working fine until today morning.
5. On the evening, For some change requests we opened the workflow in SharePoint designer but some task properties including **Form_URN**, **Outcome** are not showing in current task properties.
6. Now, these properties are showing as **[%ID9....** See below screenshot.

[image]

What would be the reason?

Please help somebody. Thank you